# Multiple Instances of Consumer and Rate Limiting with MassTransit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to configure a consumer in MassTransit to process a message and restrict the number of messages processed within a time period because I have to consume an external API that is rate-limited. To complicate things the consumer is deployed in multiple servers. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rate limiting a consumer across a horizontally scaled service is not supported out of the box by MassTransit. You would need to research a way to rate limit using a distributed rate limiter (perhaps something built using Redis, etc.) and create your own [middleware filter](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/middleware) to call that rate limiter.

Comment: Shame... but thanks for the quick response @chris-patterson